# Google Map in not Visible in android marshmallow?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Google Map not showing in marshmallow device when build an app at API level greater than 23 but it showing correctly below marshmallow version.I have used MapView.

Actally i am getting Current lat lang (0,0) in Marshmallow that's why i am facing issue in marshmallow.For getting current lat lang i am using this line:-

private void getCurrentLatLong() {

```
    try {
        gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            System.out.println("latitude print==" + latitude);


            lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
            lng = String.valueOf(longitude);
            System.out.println("lat long check====" + "lati :" + lat + " -- lng :" + lng);

            if (lat.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0") || lng.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0")) {
                getCurrentLatLong();
            } else {
                mMapView.onResume();
                setMap();
            }

        } else {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your code ?

Comment: show your code along with error logcat if error occured

Comment: @Luiz Fernando Salvaterra actually when i build the app above 23 then i am not getting the current lat lang its always (0,0) in marshmallow device but below marshmallow its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Grant app permissions first, Setting -> Your App -> Permission -> enabled require permission

Comment: And write code to enable permission or to ask permission before loading map on runtime to avoid the issue

Comment: i have done all these things but still facing this issue.